# Vertical TAB grid lines in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, notepad++

Does VS Code have the option to show vertical grid lines that correspond to TAB spaces? In Notepad++, whenever I hit TAB, I get a vertical bar that can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to check/uncheck e.g. following settings in Visual Studio Code preferences:

```
editor.tabSize: 4
editor.insertSpaces: false
editor.guides.indentation: true
```

resulting in:

[image]

Steps to configure:

1. Open your HTML file in VS Code
2. Open VS Code Settings - type e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
3. Now in the `Search settings` text box enter e.g. `editor.insertSpaces`
4. Uncheck ***Insert spaces when pressing Tab***.

Repeat steps for the preferences mentioned above.